# IIS - URL Rewrite not working when the URL has the word 'data' in it

Tags: php, .htaccess, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I'm not sure if that title makes sense but to explain it further, I have a website where every single request needs to hit my file called controller.php.

I've had this working for some time, today new directory containing pdf files was added to the site. Currently there are two files in that directory that are accessible via hyperlinks.

The two relative paths I'm accessing are: http://q360help.joehelp.com/Docs/Document_Grid_Filters.pdf

which correctly redirects to:
http://q360help.joehelp.com/controller.php?Docs/Document_Grid_Filters.pdf

AND 
http://q360help.joehelp.com/Docs/SERVERDATA.pdf 
which is *supposed* to but does not currently redirect to:
http://q360help.joehelp.com/controller.php?Docs/SERVERDATA.pdf

Instead I get a 404 error which is expected when trying to access anything that doesn't go through the controller. When I manually add the controller.php to the URL the file loads up fine. I'm just curious as to why it's not redirecting correctly. Every single other pdf file in every other directory works fine.

Here is my web.config file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configuration>
        <system.webServer>
            <httpRedirect enabled="false" destination="" />
            <rewrite>
                <rules>
                    <rule name="controller redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(http://)?(www.)?joehelp.com" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^(http://)?(www.)?q360help.joehelp.com$" ignoreCase="true" negate="false" />
                    <add input="{URL}" pattern="Data/*" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{URL}" pattern="Skins/*" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{URL}" pattern="Resources/*" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^/controller.php*$" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="/controller.php?{R:0}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
</system.webServer>
```

**EDIT:**  Upon further testing it appears that having the word 'data' anywhere within the URL is what's causing this to break. Is this a thing? I have never heard of anything like this and using the URL Redirect pattern tester through the GUI in IIS indicates that the URL  *should*  redirect.

At this point my workaround is to change the file name so it does not have 'data' in it, but I am curious to know  *why*  this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem in this line:

```
<add input="{URL}" pattern="Data/*" negate="true" />
```

Because you are using unescaped forward slash `/`, this strings will match your regexp:

- /Data/something
- **/Docs/SERVERDATA.pdf**
- /Data
- /Datasadasdas

Your solution is easy, you just need to escape this slash. Final regexp should be: `Data//*`